# How can I check if a string contains a URL in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

What is the regex pattern to determine if a URL exists in a string?

I would like to check for:

http://mydomain.com

and

http://www.mydomain.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If's not quite clear whether you want to check for specific domain or just any domain.

1. Checking for any domain in the form of `http://domain.com` or `www.domain.com`:

   `/(http:\/\/|www\.)\S+/i.test(yourString)`
2. Checking for specific mydomain.com:

   `/http:\/\/(www\.)?mydomain\.com/i.test(yourString)`

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following javascript code:

```
if(new RegExp("[a-zA-Z0-9]+://([a-zA-Z0-9_]+:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@)?([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?").test(myUrl)) {
  // TODO
}
```

Indeed the real full regex for a URL is:

```
[a-zA-Z\d]+://(\w+:\w+@)?([a-zA-Z\d.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:\d+)?(/.*)?
```

If you want, you can test 2 sites:

1. [a regex tester](http://ap2cu.com/tools/regex)
2. [a javascript tester](http://ap2cu.com/tools/javascript)

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

if you know the domain ahead of time, you can do

```
if(myString.indexOf("http://mydomain.com") != -1)
{
//substring found, do stuff
}
```

see more here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_IndexOf.asp

If you don't know the domain ahead of time, regular expressions are probably your best bet

Answer (score 0):

http://[a-z]*.[a-z]*.?[a-z]*.?[a-z]*

You can get it tested at http://www.regexplanet.com/